# SFDX - LWC1001: Unexpected compilation error: did not find a shallow_cmp function for AST_Chain

Tags: lightning-web-components, salesforcedx, vs-code

Problem:

After developing 4 LWC components then deploying to a scratch org via `SFDX: Push Source to Default Scratch Org`, the Salesforce CLI returns:

**`LWC1001: Unexpected compilation error: did not find a shallow_cmp function for AST_Chain`**

Some Details:

- All 4 LWCs do not throw errors when deployed to Local Development Server
- 1 LWC is a service component
- 2 LWC components are child components
- Running sfdx-cli/7.98.0
- Each LWC is running API version 51.0
- All are visible for each, except for service LWC
- All targets are declared for each, except for service LWC

What I have tried:

- Transfering LWCs to a new project and deploying them.
- Deploying each LWC individually.
- Updating sfdx

Result:

- Deploying from a new project and updating sfdx still returns the same error.
- But, after deploying each LWC individually, I discovered two of them cannot deploy by themselves. One of them, let's call it `c-bar`, cannot deploy because it references `c-foo` in its markup. However, when deploying just `c-foo` the CLI returns the same error--`LWC1001: Unexpected compilation error: did not find a shallow_cmp function for AST_Chain`--and VS Code points to its `foo.js-meta.xml` file. Therefore, presumably, `c-foo` is the cause so I commented both `foo.html` and `foo.js` files, as well as the `c-foo` reference in the `bar.html` markup then re-deployed `c-foo`. As a result, it was able to successfully deploy.
- When commenting *just its markup file* (`foo.html`), leaving it just `<template></template>`, the CLI returns the same compilation error which leaves me to think the `foo.js` is the cause for some reason.

Any thoughts or suggestions why a compilation error can occur from `foo.js`, when all it mainly does is listening for and dispatching events?

Comment: Likely something in your `.js` that isn't being well handled by the tooling. Suggest you post the `.js` if possible and someone may recognise some unusual coding in it so you can work-around the tooling problem by changing your `.js`. PS nice work on narrowing this down.

Comment: @KeithC Yeah, it turns out that one of the SFDX compilation tools crashes when encountered ES2020 optional chaining or null coalescing syntax. After refactoring the code using those operators, it works. 

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

> ... it turns out that one of the SFDX compilation tools **crashes when encountered ES2020 optional chaining or null coalescing syntax**. After refactoring the code using those operators, it works ...

Using optional chaining throws:

`LWC1001: Unexpected compilation error: did not find a shallow_cmp function for AST_Chain`

While using null coalescing throws:

`LWC1503: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"`